# Code metric for code redundancy or code cloning

Tags: reference-request, empirical-research

Is there a common code metric for "code redundancy" or "code cloning"?

I think I read somewhere a definition, where the LOC (lines of code) of
the redundant code was measured.

I also searched for references, but didn't find a paper that seemed like an good or trustworthy reference.

Comment: look into the software Nicad by Chanchal Roy, it does clone detection and probably gives a few metrics.

Comment: Zhenmin Li, Shan Lu, Suvda Myagmar and Yuanyuan Zhou. CP-Miner: A Tool for Finding Copy-paste and Related Bugs in Operating System Code. Proceedings of the Sixth Symposium on Operating System Design and Implementation [OSDI'04], December, 2004.  I think the authors started a company.  There is also a tool called [MOSS](http://theory.stanford.edu/~aiken/moss/) that is widely used in universities to detect cheating.  The paper that is linked at the bottom outlines their algorithm.

Comment: By the way: I _copy-pasted_ that reference to CP-Miner from Prof. Zhou's webpage. :)

Comment: Google had a "search open source software" service, which they recently discontinued.

Comment: @WanderingLogic, shouldn't that be the answer?